# C++ child changes parent member at some point between copy constructor and ouput

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, copy

If you test the following code, it compiles and runs without issue:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(bool flag) : flag(flag) {}
    virtual void display() = 0;

protected:
    bool flag;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child(bool flag) : Parent(flag) {}
    Child(const Child & rhs) : Parent(rhs.flag) {}
    virtual void display() { cout << flag << endl; }
};

int main() 
{
    // Set Flag to true
    Child tru(true);
    Child * storage [2]; 
    storage[0] = new Child(tru);
    storage[0]->display();

    // Set Flag to false
    Child * container = new Child(storage[0]);
    delete storage[0];
    storage[0] = new Child(false);
    storage[0]->display();

    // Set Flag to true
    storage[1] = new Child(container);
    storage[1]->display();

    return 0;
}
```

However, after I plug this snippet into my program, the **Child objects** consistently change their **bool flag** to **true** between the time they are created with the **copy constructor** and the time I actually attempt to display their **bool flag** value. I know the change initially sticks thanks to copious amounts of **cout** lines calling values at every step of the way, but when my display function is called, their values all switch to true.

I haven't been able to successfully reproduce the error, externally, but while I attempt to do so, I'm hoping someone might have an idea of what could possibly interfere with this process? Is there a common error, mistake or conflict I should be checking for in a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storage[1] = new Child(container);` will create the new object passing the pointer container to the new object.
I seriously doubt this is what you intended. Did you mean to type `storage[1] = new Child(*container);` (passing the reference to the pointed-to object?)

Remember a pointer is (essentially) a numerical-address, thus can evaluate to `true` (!= 0) or `false` ( == 0), thus:
`storage[1] = new Child(container);` evaluates as `storage[1] = new Child(container != 0);` (and that is `new Child(0xffcd3ds != 0); //example memory address`, thus calling the standard constructor taking bool, rather than the copy-constructor.

Take into account that that error also specifies the same issue one line 32 `Child * container = new Child(storage[0]);`, the exact same bug can be found here (thus container's object will be false anyway), however it's slightly more subtle given `child * []` can be used as `child **`. But I imagine you can figure it out with ease.

Note that this kind of comparison may seem like a "trap" if your learning programming, however I assure you, such quick-and-dirty "is the pointer null" comparisons are a huge help in more complex projects.

In furtherance, I ran your snippet though the Visual-Studio compiler - it output the following compile log (successfully building the project)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  playground.cpp
1>c:\users\USER\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project1\playground.cpp(32): warning C4800: 'Child *': forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\USER\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project1\playground.cpp(38): warning C4800: 'Child *': forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

*(the following is not meant to have any emotion, I realize on reading it does sound somewhat sarcastic, it is meant in sincerity).*
Note that those two warnings (effectively) tell you what I just did above, assuming whatever compiler you are using outputs a similar error (I'd be surprised if it didn't), the lesson here will be what I tell my apprentice every-day, **always read the compiler-output log** - obviously if your compiler doesn't output such a warning, remember the lesson anyway.

**Slightly useful tip**
If you are able to do so, please consider using the [C++11 Smart Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx), I note that you never call `delete` before you `return 0`, doing so is a *soft* error, and may leak memory on some systems.

Comment: I'm currently coding in Notepad++ and PuTTY through to Linux, so I don't, presently, have a robust enough compiler to provide warnings like what you pointed out. Everything I've used to compile it with (ideone included) compiled without a peep! I've made the correction you pointed out to my code, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Having said that, I think there is some truth to the idea that I'm forcing true/false statements where I didn't mean to be. Can you see any potential issues that could arise from things like pushing classes to different scopes with extern and the like?

Comment: Did you take into account that both lines 32 and 38 are at fault? I only pointed out the error on line 38.

Comment: @ProzaicMuze IE: Child * container = new Child(storage[0]);  //this will also yield false (you wanted what's pointed to by storage[0]). *Also if I might ask, using an SSH to a Linux box sounds - well pretty amazingly hardcore, May I ask why your using such an environment? (It sounds like *fun*)*

Comment: The changes compiled, externally, but my program spit out the following when I adjusted line 32 as follows: **Child * container = new Child(*storage[0])** ---- error: no matching function for call to ‘Child::Child(Parent&)’
note: candidates are: Child::Child(const Child&)
note:                 Child::Child(bool)

Comment: @ProzaicMuze , I belive you must have changed the type of Storage from Child * [] to Parent * [] - as my recommended change compiles for me.